# How to connect to icloud.com with Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to connect to **https://icloud.com** using selenium, but I keep timing out while trying to find the email input, which has `id='account_name_text_field'`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://icloud.com')

try:
    email_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.ID, 'account_name_text_field')))
except TimeoutException:
    print('timed out at email_input')
    driver.close()


email_input.send_keys('johndoe@icloud.com')
email_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
password_input = driver.find_element_by_id('password_text_field')
password_input.send_keys('password')
password_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The email and password inputs are in an iframe, so I needed to switch the driver context to the iframe:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

def main(email, password):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('https://icloud.com/')

    delay = 20

    WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, 'auth-frame')))

    email_input = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'account_name_text_field')))
    email_input.send_keys(email)
    email_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    password_input = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'password_text_field')))
    password_input.send_keys(password)
    password_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Now that you can sign in, glhf trying to get past 2FA...